# Ubuntu 18.04 sound failed on Thinkpad

Tags: ubuntu, audio, thinkpad

Since several days ago (something automatically upgraded), I get no sound out of my Lenovo Thinkpad 470s laptop model [20HFCTO1WW](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t470s/20hf/20hfcto1ww/documentation) with Ubuntu 18.04. I tried several things other similar threads suggested:

> pacmd list-cards

returns 0 cards

> lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio

returns nothing, and

> pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload

and rebooting does nothing. There are [many](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059619/sound-card-shown-as-dummy-output-in-ubuntu-18-04) [posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099053/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-dummy-output-no-sound?noredirect=1&lq=1) about this all over the interwebs but no solution work for me.

**Q1:** How do I get my sound back?

**Q2:** This seems like a fairly catastrophic defect that's not getting enough publicity -- does anyone know what happened in apt-get upgrade to have caused this? Is it "a part of the package" associated with a FOSS OS, i.e. its instability? As much as I dislike Windows, I can't recollect anything similar ever happening.

**UPDATE 1:** Ubuntu just auto-updated and the details of the update indicated Thinkpad-related updates. After that, the Settings don't show dummy output anymore and `pacmd list-cards` and `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio` are no longer empty, however, there is still no sound coming out.

**UPDATE 2:** After removing the pulse config (`https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133074/after-dummy-sound-output-got-fixed-by-ubuntu-update-speakers-work-but-not-headp`), I get sound but only coming out of the speakers. When I plug my headphones, I get no sound.

**UPDATE 3:** I lost sound again, only `Dummy Output` showing in Settings.

Comment: My laptop S/N is PC0LRK1T, it's a T470, about 2 yrs old. I will do the bootable USB tomorrow

Comment: What happens when you boot from a https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/ ? Please click [edit] and update your question with the information we will need to solve this.

Comment: I just booted from a newly created USB, got brand new Ubuntu for the time being, however still no sound (dummy output).